# what is formal way to ask "may we know why this happened and how it happened?"

Tags: american-english

what is formal way to ask "may we know why this happened and how it happened?"

is this phrase correct .What is the formal and better way of asking this

Comment: You may want to see [ell.se](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), where language learners' questions are addressed. As it is, I would say `Could I please have an explanation for how and why this happened?` is sufficiently formal, __but__ more context would be useful.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Could you explain the circumstances leading up to/concerning this event?" - (The how any why are implied...)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> "*Would you mind informing us how and why this happened?*"

Or, alternately:

> "*We would appreciate it if you could inform us how and why this happened.*"

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

"If you don't mind, Can you tell us how and why this happened?"

Answer (score 0):

> Would you be kind enough to inform us how and why this happened?

Or, alternatively:

> We would be grateful if you informed us how and why this happened?

Your sentence comes off as polite, but not necessarily formal.

Comment: Also, you have to take into context the type of scenario. It sometimes pays to be a little more forceful if the situation calls for, so you could also say things like: "The public deserves to know how and why this has happened.", or "There are many unanswered questions as to how and why this happened."

Answer (score -1):

*Why* this happened is the reason for it; *how* this happened is asking about what caused it, so you could ask for that specific information. You could add *Thank you* as a courtesy.

> It would be useful [or *helpful* or some other adjective] to understand the cause of this as well as the reason for it. Thank you.